# How can I check that the PHP multi-dimentional array has at least one value?

Tags: php

Here is the PHP array I have. This array **string key** can be more or low. So how can I check if any **string key** has at leas one value?

```
Array
(
    [Administrator] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Editor] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Author] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Contributor] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Subscriber] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Shop_Manager] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Shop_Accountant] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Shop_Worker] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [Shop_Vendor] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [EDD_Subscriber] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

I want to show a error message if all **string key** is empty but if any **string key** has value then Its okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function user_has_roles($arr){
    foreach( $arr as $el) {
        if (isset($el[0])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
if (user_has_roles($arr)) {
    // Do something if it has values
} else {
    // Do something if it does not have values
}
```

Or for error checking you can straight go:

```
if (!user_has_roles($arr)) {
    throw new Exception('User does not have any roles.');
}
```

Comment: Hope it helps! Please consider leaving upvote and accepting the answer, so it might help other people in similar cases.